# how to animate change of vstack containers height in swiftui?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

There is a screen with the background and logo in the center. On view loading, it should shrink to the half on the phone height (keeping logo in center) and the form should appear below taking the bottom part of the screen - sliding from the bottom. On my attempt to animate the offset of the bottom form, I still initially observe white background for some reason, why? And how it's possible to overcome that?

```
   ...

   @State var offset: CGFloat = 1000;
   
   ...

   var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometryProxy in
            NavigationView {
                VStack {
                    VStack {
                        ZStack(alignment: .center) {
                            Color.init(red: 255 / 255, green: 222 / 255, blue: 68 / 255)
                                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                                    Image.init(systemName: "pencil")
                        }
                    }
                    VStack {
                        Text("hello-world")
                        Text("hello-world")
                        Text("hello-world")
                    }
                    .offset(y: self.offset)
                    .onAppear {
                            let baseAnimation = Animation.easeInOut(duration: 1)
                            let repeated = baseAnimation.speed(1)
                            return withAnimation(repeated) {
                                self.offset = 0
                            }
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

On the initial load of the screen, I see the white background on where the form should be, how to get rid of it? I tried frame height animation as well but it does not meet the requirements.

Comment: If i understand correctly, you want the form to first be hidden and then animates going from bottom to the center below the logo. is that correct?

Comment: Confirm if this is the animation you are looking for please: https://gifyu.com/image/WNjx (be patient with the .gif :D)

Comment: Yes, but the top container should shrink in order to retain the logo in center